# arrange() not responding in R

Tags: r, dplyr

When I run the following code in R, there is no difference between `t` and `f`. I am attempting to sort the values of column x greatest to largest. What am I doing wrong here?

```
library(dplyr)

tib <- tibble(x=c(4,2,6,33,1), y=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))

t <- arrange(tib, x, ascending=TRUE)
f <- arrange(tib, x, ascending=FALSE)

print(t)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The help documentation `?arrange` does not show an ascending argument. Try

```
a <- arrange(tib, x)
d <- arrange(tib, desc(x))

print(a)
print(d)
```